# Type casting object[] to generic type K which is also an array

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I try to write a generic type casting method which will work for both complex objects and  arrays of objects. Below is my code:

```
public void Test()
{
     MyClass2[] t2 = m.MapItem<MyClass1[], MyClass2[]>(t1);
     return;
}

public K MapItem<T, K>(T source)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray && typeof(K).IsArray)
    {
        Type ek = typeof(K).GetElementType();
        IList sourceList = (IList)source;
        List<object> tmp = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; i++)
        {
            var k = Activator.CreateInstance(ek);
            tmp.Add(k);
        }
        var resultObj = tmp.ToArray();
        MapItem(source, resultObj);

        //Here i have resultObj is an object[] of the results,
        //which is to be casted result type K
        //BUT DOES NOT WORK!!!
        return (K)Convert.ChangeType(resultObj, typeof(K));

    }
    else
    {
        MethodInfo myMapperMethod = GetMyMapperMethodForThisType(typeof(T), typeof(K));
        return (K)myMapperMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source });
    }
}

public K MapItem<T, K>(T source, K dest)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray && typeof(K).IsArray)
    {
        IList sourceList = (IList)source;
        IList destList = (IList)dest;
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; i++)
        {
            MapItem(sourceList[i], destList[i]);
        }
        return dest;
    }
    else
    {
        MethodInfo myMapperMethod = GetMyMapperMethodForThisType(typeof(T),typeof(K));
        return (K) myMapperMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, dest });
    }
}

private MethodInfo GetMyMapperMethodForThisType(Type type1, Type type2)
{
    //some code to find appropriate function...
}
```

But, `return (K) Convert.ChangeType(y, typeof(K));` cannot cast from `object[]` to `K`. How can I do this casting to return `K` from `object[]`?

Note: json serialization works but I don't want to use reflection or serialization.

```
  string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultObj);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<K>(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally I think you want to avoid using `List<object>` at all. You should just create the array of the right size:

```
IList dest = Array.CreateInstance(ek, sourceList.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; i++)
{
    dest[i] = Activator.CreateInstance(ek);
}
K result = (K) dest;
// Note that this is calling MapItem<T, K>, not MapItem<T, object[]>
MapItem(source, result);
return result;
```